# 500 error page not showing on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, custom-error-pages

I'm trying to get a custom 500 error page to show on Heroku, running rails 3.2.11

I've followed the steps at:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages

The process worked fine for the maintenance page, but doesn't seem to work for the error page.  I'm positive the S3 URL is correct in Heroku, and when I visit the S3 URL directly I can view the error page just fine (it is set to public).

config.consider_all_requests_local is set to false in production.rb

Any ideas as to why Heroku is not showing it?  I just get a blank screen in various browsers (Chrome says it's a 500 error but doesn't render a page).

Comment: There's a setting in your app's dashboard to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Ian.  I can copy the S3 url directly from the dashboard into my browser and I see the appropriate page.  So why would Heroku not pick it up through the app?

Comment: How are you testing that your app doesn't show it?  This is the error page that is shown when your app doesn't work - not when it's working and throwing an exception.

For example, if your app doesn't start - it should show the page.  Break your app somehow (for example, change the config so it doesn't start successfully on Heroku).

Comment: Thanks for the insight Jon. So if my application throws a 500 error, it will not trigger Heroku's page -- is that correct?

Comment: @tyler have you figured out if the error page is supposed to be displayed when you have a 500?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The heroku's custom error page isn't displayed whenever an exception occurs in your application.

Your application is responsible for displaying this kind of pages.
See [using exceptions_app with rails 3.2](https://coderwall.com/p/w3ghqq).

The error page happens when an error occurs with heroku.

The [devcenter page about error pages](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages) says, about testing your error page :

> To test your error page, you can push a bad deploy such as putting a syntax error into a key configuration file, or by creating a path on your app that sleeps for 35 seconds (thereby triggering the error H12 Request Timeout.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out and they actually just updated the documentation to make it clearer after I pointed out how the former wording could be confusing.