# Heroku 500 Internal Server Error on broken pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, internal-server-error

My app is being hosted on Heroku and when I go to a broken page on my website (ie. www.example.herokuapp.com/mumbojumbo), i get a 500 Internal Server Error message.

Obviously, when I go to a broken page something will go wrong, I would just prefer it to show the Oops error page that I made that's on an Amazson s3 like Heroku suggests.

How can I fix this?

Right now, I already have a custom Error Page that set up in Heroku.

Comment: Did you set the Heroku config variable for the error page?  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages#customize-pages

Comment: Yes I did set them already

Comment: And restarted the dynos?

Comment: Yep when you set the variables it automatically restarts the app

Comment: Seems like this was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351239/500-error-page-not-showing-on-heroku
It suggests a testing technique (from the doc) and an alternative to Heroku's error page.